# Codeigniter issues with paths in localhost (XAMPP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, path, controller

The index page (aka homepage.php) in my code igniter install is working fine no matter what.

The problem lies with using subdirectories to store other pages, currently its setup like:
[image: img1]

loading homepage like `http://localhost/VAw_CI/` works fine (loading homepage.php), this is setup in routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/homepage";
```

in config.php, I've setup:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/VAw_CI';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I specified `$config['index_page'] = '';` above, because I modified my .htaccess located in `htdocs`like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*homepage/$0 [PT,L]
```

However, if I try to login on homepage.php, which is currently looks like:
[image: img2]

It sends me to `http://localhost/VAw_CI/pages/clientlogin`

displaying:
[image: img3]

I have controllers setup like:
[image: img4]

What gives here? When I visit `http://localhost/VAw_CI`, it is effectively loading the `views->pages->homepage.php` view properly, but it seems any other view doesn't work am I missing some path setup somewhere for pages *other* than the index (homepage.php) in my case?

Comment: I think you're mistaking controllers with views..."pages" are (usually) controllers, which in turn call views to render their output. I suggest reading CI manual and/or something about MVC

Comment: I used the pages/ dir as a subdir in both /controllers/pages and views/pages as a way to categorize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please create .htaccess file in project folder and write:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

You don't need to define in base_url in config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; // blank it.
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought this was included by default. It isn't. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Yes, @MarcoW. It is included. But here i've give a answer of the question...:)

Comment: you solved a problem chatGPT refused to solve in 2days. Thanks. Im new to codeIgniter though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong:

I needed to be accessing : `http://localhost/VAw_CI/**index.php**/pages/aboutus` which is really strange because my default CI page is set to $config['index_page'] = 'homepage';

Hope this helps someone, sometime :)