# How can I remove "index.php" from my links?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Normally I access a page like this: `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/auth/login`
However I want to be able to access to the page like this : `http://localhost/codeigniter/auth/login`

I have no information about `http.conf` and `.htaccess` configurations.

I have set `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `codeigniter/application/config/config.php`

my http.conf file is at its default except uncommentnig "`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`"

I inspected many proposed .htaccess files but I could not understand the logic behind the rewriting rules.

Here is the most successful `.htaccess` content for me. It is located at `/www/CodeIgniter/` .
(by the most successful I mean that this is the only one that gives 404 error created by the CodeIgniter not by the server.)

```
    RewriteOptions Inherit
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(images|assets|uploads|captcha)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 index.php

</IfModule>
```

I hate requesting direct solutions however unfortunately, it is my last resort :/
Can you give me a right solution to my problem?

Comment: Try to replace `RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/` for this `RewriteBase /`

Comment: That `.htaccess` file looks more or less correct.  Possibly a CodeIgniter issue if the links are not getting through. The bit after `RewriteBase`, as manix says, is the path after your domain to the main directory where your .htaccess is, which you state is `/CodeIgniter/` so that should be correct.

Comment: is rewritemodule  enabled on your server ? check if your .htaccess file is working .[link](http://jappler.com/blog/archive/2008/10/22/how-to-test-htaccess-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my repeat answer:
[Codeigniter issues with paths in localhost (XAMPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146395/codeigniter-issues-with-paths-in-localhost-xampp/13154286#13154286)

please create .htaccess file in project folder and write:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

You don't need to define in base_url in config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; // blank it.
```

Answer (score 0):

put this on your htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

**make sure the rewrite module is enabled on your server**

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest one i found which works for me :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```