# Page 404 CodeIgniter index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes, http-status-code-404

I have this problem regarding Codeigniter, unfortunately other posts regarding this problem in this site does not help me or I did not apply it well.

**Edits* Added Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

My Directory Structure:

- scheduler(main folder)

  - **system**

    - **application**

      - config(folder)
      - controller(folder)

        - **BS.php**
  - and other folders and files
  - **index.php**

As the title says, when I type

**http://mysite.com/folder/index.php**

It outputs Page 404 not found. But, when I typed **http://mysite.com/scheduler/index.php/BS** it shows "This is a BS File" since I echoed it using the code below.

**BS.php**

```
 function index($flag = NULL)
{

 echo "This is a BS File.";
 }
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "BS";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
```

**index.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$system_folder = "system";

$application_folder = "application";

if (strpos($system_folder, '/') === FALSE)
{
    if (function_exists('realpath') AND @realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;
    }
}
else
{
    // Swap directory separators to Unix style for consistency
    $system_folder = str_replace("\\", "/", $system_folder); 
}

define('EXT', '.php');
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));
define('BASEPATH', $system_folder.'/');

if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}
else
{
    if ($application_folder == '')
    {
        $application_folder = 'application';
    }
    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}

require_once BASEPATH.'codeigniter/CodeIgniter'.EXT;
```

And lastly, my **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. "/scheduler/";
$config['secure_base_url'] = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. "/scheduler/";

$config['index_page'] = "index.php";

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Doing it for days now, still not a single process has given. Would be glad for any help.

Comment: U need HTACCESS to remove INDEX.PHP from URL

Comment: It is working as expected. What's the issue here?

Comment: I edited my question, please look in the uppermost part of my question you'll see a screenshot of my problem.

Comment: Looks like some BS for sure. Have you tried `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`? Also, if possible, try upgrading to a recent version of Codeigniter. Looks like you're still using version 1.

Comment: i am still not getting what you are trying to do.... if you want your url to be like, `http://mysite.com/folder/`, then create a folder inside the public html or htdocs folder, and put the `index.php` there with all JS and CSS. Rest of the files, put it outside public access.

Comment: @itachi: I think the "folder/index.php" URL he used as an example was incorrect/mistake - check out the URLs in the address bar of the screen shots, that should clarify. Oh and +1 because Wesley's gotta stick together ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it, 
As shown above in my question, remember the directory structure?

In the Controller folder, I have this BS.php file. Then, if I were not mistaken, it's about the case sensitivity of the file. Which is probably due to the domain that does not support capital letters in a file name which I read about it in some answers in other questions in this site.

so in short, I made **BS.file**, into **bs.file**. which it worked.

**Edit**

Also, in **routes.php** I changed BS to bs.

Comment: and dont forget to change the apache configuration as mentioned in stackoverflow.com/a/14807463/1537413

Answer (score 1):

you should remove code from index.php file and create .htaccess file in root directory of your web application. (i.e. application,system folder exist).

It's my repeat answer:
[Codeigniter issues with paths in localhost (XAMPP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146395/codeigniter-issues-with-paths-in-localhost-xampp/13154286#13154286)

please create .htaccess file in project folder and write:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

You don't need to define in base_url in config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; // blank it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have posted the codes for index.php. I don't see a need for you since you should try not to edit anything there.

Have you got .htaccess in your root folder?

I always keep this .htaccess file handy whenever I develop any CI applications.

http://pastebin.com/nTsThZHv

Comment: I event put .htaccess in my root still does not work. I even overwrite my .htaccess the thing that you gave to me, still does not work. :l

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the constroller's case problem, but a little different with @Brain's answer.
It is because I use a default controller named as "AxxxxBxxx.php". I always got a 404 error.
After I change it to "Axxxxbxxxx.php" and change the corresponding class name.
It works.

BTW, I use codeigniter 3.0. Hope it helps!